# How can I use Windows absolute paths with the movie filter on FFmpeg?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I want to do something like `-filter_complex "movie=C:\\User\\...\\file"` but I can't because of the `:` in the Windows path. I tried escaping it with a `\` but no luck. I've figured out how to get around it by making everything else an aboslute path and running the command in the same directory as the file I need for the movie filter, but the only reason that works is because I only have a single movie filter. I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: *"I'm hoping there's a better way."* The better way is to avoid the movie filter. Often the movie filter is not needed, but the rest of the command is hidden so I can't confirm this.

Comment: @llogan I have two videos and I'm overlaying one on top of the other, I need the background (the shorter of the two) to loop until the what I'm overlaying on top of it has finished. I was using `movie=filepath:loop=0, setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB` as I saw in this answer https://superuser.com/questions/1093507/loop-a-video-overlay-with-ffmpeg. Can I do this without the movie filter?

Comment: See new answer in [Loop a video overlay with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/1528899/)

Answer (score 3):

This method is working for me,
you have to escape:

- colon `:` with double back slash `\\`
- back slash `\` with slash `/`

so the command will be like this

```
"movie=C\\:/\Users/\Toshiba/\Pictures/\test vcp/\shopi pro.mp4 bla bla bla"
```

for original absolute path is `"C:\Users\Toshiba\Pictures\test vcp\shopi pro.mp4"`

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. In a windows batch file I'm doing this: movie=C\\:/\Users/\me/\Downloads/\watermark.png [watermark];

But with a nodejs library node-fluent-ffmpeg I have to do this to get it working:
movie=C\\\\:/\\Users/\\me/\\Downloads/\\watermark.png [watermark];

This might be helpful to some https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Notes-on-filtergraph-escaping

Comment: At last!  This pain of the insanity governing FFMPEG file handling is at least solved ... using an also insane method!  Thanks @Jeandré

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this is one working method.

```
-filter_complex "movie=C\\:/User/.../file"
```

Comment: I don't have my old environment set up anymore, so there's always a chance I'm typing in something wrong, but I can't get this to work.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report. Which shell?