# How to write ffmpeg windows command for file path inside double quotes option

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

please help

I want to use ffmpeg for my c # application but an error appears

this is my code

```
videoPath = @"c:\location\in.mp4";
tempVideoPath = @"c:\another_location\out.mp4";

process.StartInfo.FileName = @"ffmpeg.exe";
    
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-loop 1 -i \""+tbBGFrame.Text+ "\" -vf \"movie=\""+videoPath+ "\",scale=1900:-1[inner];[in][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[out]\" -y \""+tempVideoPath+"\"";
```

the problem is inside movie parameter. i have to include video path inputed by user but its give an error because its already double quote exist before.

its successfully if i try on windows cmd like this

```
> cd "C:\Users\Toshiba\Pictures\test vcp\input_mp4_dir\"
> ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -i Coronavirus00000000.jpg -vf "movie=input.mp4,scale=1180:-1[inner];[in][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[out]" -y out.mp4
```

but how i can run that command wihtout change directory to input.mp4 directory?

Comment: How can double quotes exist in the path already? Double quotes are forbidden in filenames and directory names on Windows. If you mean there are quotes at the start and end of the user input, you could trim them using `tbBGFrame.Text.Trim('"')`.

Comment: my filename and directory name doesn't have double quote. i use double qoute to pointing to its location, like 

cd "c:\file_location\"

Comment: OK, so what is the problem you're facing? Could you provide the value assigned to `process.StartInfo.Arguments` so that we're all on the same page?

Comment: user input doesnt have double quote. its ffmpeg command problem.

i dont know how to use ffmpeg movie filter with video input parameter using path location

Comment: what i want is something like this

`ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -i Coronavirus00000000.jpg -vf "movie="c:\location\input.mp4",scale=1180:-1[inner];[in][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[out]" -y out.mp4`

Comment: as you can see, inside movie parameter there is another double quote `"c:\location\input.mp4"` thats what make the command error. my question is how to write `c:\location\input.mp4` in a single line ffmpeg with movie parameter command without change directory first to `c:\location\`

Comment: It looks like you might need a single quote ( ' ) though I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: i have tested single quote. its give me the same result. not work

Comment: this is the error when using single quote

`[Parsed_movie_0 @ 0676dc40] Failed to avformat_open_input 'C'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0613cc40] Error initializing filter 'movie' with args 'C:\Users\Toshiba\Pictures\test vcp\shopi pro bot shopee untuk meningkatkan penjualan seller shopee.mp4'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: No such file or directory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60449126/

Comment: thank you @Gyan ,answer on that threat is not working, but give me an inspiration and i found my answer. posted there.